# How to store double into an array and modify it

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm to create a banking program. I should be able to deposit, withdrawl, view balance, and then of course exit.

My problem is we have not gone over arrays yet and that is what I'm trying to use. When I initialize the array with [0] as it's only one type of data at a time, i recieve an:
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

So my question is how can I be able to do this while modififying the balance until the user exits. I'm a bit stuck...

Any help is appreciated and I apoligize in advance for the messy code.

Thankyou everyone for the help. I did put: double[] balance = new double[1];

But now I am returning to the problem that I can't continue modifying the array with more deposits, and withdrawls. I initializes it back to 0.0.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Main class:

```java
public class Project3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Introduction();
        Banking obj1 = new Banking();

    }
    public static void Introduction() 
    {

        //this message tells the user exactly what this program does.

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "This is a small conversion program which allows you to do "    
                           + "\nDeposit "
                           + "\nWithdrawl."
                           + "\nView Balance."
                           + "\nExit",
                   "Conversion Calculator",
                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Class:

```java
public class Banking 
{
    double deposit;
    double newbalance;

    double[] balance = new double[0];

    public Banking() 
    {
        Menu();
    }
    public void Menu() 
    {
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);                             
        Object[] selectionValues = { "Deposit", "Withdrawl"};
        String initialSelection = "Deposit";
        Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to "
               + "do today?",
            "Home Banking Selection Screen", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, selectionValues, initialSelection);      
        // If statements used to call the method selected      
        if (selection == "Deposit")
            Deposit();
        if (selection == "Withdrawl")
            Withdrawl();
    }
    public void Deposit() 
    {
         balance[0] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter the total number of degrees in Fahrenheit to be Converted into Celcius? and press 'Ok'",
                "Deposit",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));  

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "You doposited $ " +balance+ "\n You now have $" ,
                "The End",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


         JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);                             
        Object[] selectionValues = { "Continue with more transactions", "Exit"};
        String initialSelection = "Deposit";
        Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to "
               + "do today?",
            "Home Banking Selection Screen", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, selectionValues, initialSelection);      
        // If statements used to call the method selected      
        if (selection == "Continue witl more transactions")
            Menu();
        if (selection == "Exit")
            Exit();
    }
    public void Withdrawl() 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "          Will be Withdrawl!", //Message to tell the user the program has ended
                "2",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);   
    }
    public void Exit() 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "          Thank you and have a great day!", //Message to tell the user the program has ended
                "The End",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your double array is of size 0, you need an array of at least size 1 to access the 0th index. Also, why are you using an array for this at all?

Comment: `double[] balance = new double[1];` try this

Comment: I'm new to this and thought it was the best approach but I welcome a different suggestion if it is not to advanced for me to apply.

Comment: @ehlert5290 NB: never _ever_ store money in a double. You will sooner or later find rounding errors and your customers [w/c/sh]ould be _very_ disappointed...

Comment: A float would be better?

Comment: @ehlert5290 no, it would be worse. You need either a non decimal type (int, long -> represent cents instead of dollars)  or an enhanced decimal object: ``BigDecimal``

Answer (score 0):

`double[] balance = new double[0];` Does not create an array of 0
's.

For example: Your array does not look like this:

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Instead your array looks like this:

[ ]

Saying `Object obj = new Object[x]` creates an array that is of length `x`. However, even then the items in the array are not initialized. You have to go manually set each one to ***0***.

Comment: You answer may be confusing for him. When working with an `double[]`, all values will be actually intialized with 0. For example when creating `new double[5]` it will actually be `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` and NOT `[null, null, null, null, null]`

Answer (score 0):

You have a double array of size 0:

```
double[] balance = new double[0];
```

And then you are accessing it's first (non-existing element):

```
balance[0] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please enter the total number of degrees in Fahrenheit to be Converted into Celcius? and press 'Ok'",
            "Deposit",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));
```

That's why the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` is thrown.

Just use `double[] balance = new double[1];`
Here is size of array you are going to create ^

Every element will be initialised with `0.0` by default.

UPD: actually, you might want to try adding some checking to ensure that the user you are touching actually exists and the balance is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just initialize your array this way:
`double[] balance = {};`

At this point the size of the array will be zero.

However, based of your question, I do not think you need and array.
Simply declare balance this way:

```
double balance = 0.00d;
```

When you deposit:
`balance = balance + depositAmount;`

when you withdraw:
`balance = balance - withdrawlAmount;`

Comment: That was very helpful thank you. I just can't keep the balance from 'resetting' when I make another transaction like another deposit